# Swift class to check ApplePencil reachability

Tags: swift, ios, bluetooth

I've implemented a class that lets you check out whether there is an ApplePencil connected to the device or not.

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class ApplePencilReachability: NSObject {

    fileprivate let centralManager = CBCentralManager()

    var pencilReachabilityDidChangeClosure:((_ isAvailable: Bool) -> Void)?

    var isPencilReachable = false
    var timer: Timer?

    convenience init(didChangeClosure:@escaping ((_ isAvailable: Bool) -> Void)) {

        self.init()

        centralManager.delegate = self

        pencilReachabilityDidChangeClosure = didChangeClosure
    }

    @objc fileprivate func checkReachability() {

        let peripherals = centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: "180A")])
        let wasPencilReachable = isPencilReachable

        isPencilReachable = peripherals.contains(where: isApplePencil)

        if wasPencilReachable != isPencilReachable {

            pencilReachabilityDidChangeClosure?(isPencilReachable)
        }

        if isPencilReachable {

            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func isApplePencil(peripheral: CBPeripheral) -> Bool {

        return peripheral.name == "Apple Pencil"
    }
}

// MARK: CBCentralManagerDelegate

extension ApplePencilReachability: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

        if central.state == .poweredOn {

            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(checkReachability), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
        else {

            timer?.invalidate()

            pencilReachabilityDidChangeClosure?(false)
        }
    }
}
```

It really like to get some tipps to improve this class and make it more 'swifty', if possible :)

This class is also available open-source on [Github](https://github.com/DBocksteger/ApplePencilReachability) so feel free to submit Pull-Requests for improvements :)

While writing this class I was inspired by HAS' answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542250/detect-whether-apple-pencil-is-connected-to-an-ipad-pro/41264961#41264961) on this topic.

Comment: It might be pure chance, but your code looks quite similar to this one posted on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41264961/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR this answer was an inspiration to write this code like it looks like, but thinks like the extension aren't there. Also I've added an conenience initializer which takes directly the closure to notify the callee.

Comment: What's the point of it being a subclass of NSObject?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ - It wasn't possible to extend the class, if i do not subclass from `NSObject`, because the class doesn't conform to `NSObjectProtocol` then.